# spread a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to spread certain column of a dataframe in python.

In R I would use this function:

[image]

In python I just found the `df.pivot_table()`, but I just got an error:

```
   pandas.pivot_table(df, values= 'Value', index=['Day', 'Money', 'Product'],columns=['Account'])
                                                  ^
```

**Update Outcome:
The dataframe didn't changed. It only returned the same dataframe without spreading**

What is a good way to spread the account column, taking in consideration the value column ?

```
Day Money Product   Account              Value 
D01 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194
D02 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194
D03 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194
D04 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194
D05 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194
D06 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194
D07 R$     000013   Volume              96.774194                                                                             
...
D02 R$     000013   PrecoVenda           0.132258
D03 R$     000013   PrecoVenda           0.132258
D04 R$     000013   PrecoVenda           0.132258
D05 R$     000013   PrecoVenda           0.132258
D06 R$     000013   PrecoVenda           0.132258
D07 R$     000013   PrecoVenda           0.132258
```

Comment: It's a syntax error, you're just missing a comma after `'Value'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a comma before index:

```
pandas.pivot_table(df, values= 'Value', index=['Day', 'Money', 'Product'],columns=['Account'])
```

Comment: Sorry, It is true. But the outcome still returns the same dataframe

Comment: I got the write result now